# How to scrape pdf urls from list of journal editions using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape all the pdf urls from the journal volume urls I already have.

This is the list of journal volumes:

```
add_url = ['http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=1',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=10',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=100',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=101',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=102',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=103',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=104',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=105',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=106',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=107',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=108',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=109',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=11',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=110',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=111',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=112',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=113',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=114',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=115',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=116',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=117',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=118',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=119',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=12',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=120',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=121',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=122',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=123',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=124',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=125',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=126',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=127',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=128',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=129',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=13',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=130',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=131',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=132',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=133',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=134',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=135',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=136',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=137',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=138',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=139',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=14',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=140',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=141',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=142',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=143',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=144',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=145',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=146',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=147',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=148',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=149',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=15',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=150',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=151',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=152',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=153',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=154',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=155',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=156',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=157',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=158',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=159',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=16',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=160',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=161',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=162',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=163',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=164',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=165',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=166',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=167',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=168',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=169',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=17',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=170',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=171',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=172',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=173',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=174',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=175',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=176',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=177',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=178',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=179',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=18',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=180',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=181',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=182',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=183',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=184',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=185',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=186',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=187',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=188',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=189',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=19',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=190',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=191',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=192',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=193',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=194',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=195',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=196',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=197',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=198',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=199',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=2',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=20',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=200',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=201',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=202',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=203',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=204',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=205',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=206',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=207',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=208',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=209',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=21',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=210',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=211',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=212',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=213',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=214',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=215',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=216',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=217',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=218',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=219',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=22',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=220',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=221',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=222',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=223',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=224',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=225',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=227',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=23',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=231',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=232',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=233',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=234',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=235',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=236',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=237',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=238',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=239',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=24',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=240',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=241',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=242',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=243',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=244',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=245',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=246',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=247',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=248',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=249',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=25',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=250',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=251',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=252',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=253',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=254',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=255',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=256',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=258',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=259',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=26',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=260',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=261',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=262',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=263',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=264',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=265',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=266',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=267',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=268',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=269',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=27',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=270',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=271',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=273',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=274',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=275',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=276',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=277',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=278',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=279',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=28',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=280',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=281',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=282',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=283',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=284',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=29',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=3',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=30',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=31',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=32',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=33',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=34',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=35',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=36',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=37',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=38',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=39',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=40',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=41',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=42',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=43',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=44',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=45',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=46',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=47',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=48',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=49',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=5',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=50',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=51',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=52',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=53',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=54',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=55',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=56',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=57',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=58',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=59',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=60',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=61',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=62',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=63',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=64',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=65',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=66',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=67',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=68',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=69',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=70',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=71',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=72',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=73',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=74',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=75',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=76',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=77',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=78',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=79',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=8',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=80',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=81',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=82',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=83',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=84',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=85',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=86',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=87',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=88',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=89',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=9',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=90',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=91',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=92',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=93',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=94',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=95',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=96',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=97',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=98',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=99']
```

Analyzing the DOM of each of these urls I noticed that all the pdfs have the same similarity:

```
audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2
```

The code I tried to write to get all these pdfs from each volume is the following:

```
for i in add_url:
    pag = requests.get(i)
    parser = BeautifulSoup(pag.text, "html.parser")
    doi_list = []
    for a in parser.find_all("a", href=True):
        if "audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2" in a["href"]:
            doi_list.append(a["href"])
add_doi = []
for i in doi_list:
    html2 = "http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/" + i
    add_doi.append(html2)
```

But why do I only get a few pdf urls and not all of them from each volume url?

```
OUTPUT
['http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=99&nomeArquivo=v05_n3_00-sumario.pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2778&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_58_v05_n3_(1).pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2785&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_60_v05_n3_(2).pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2792&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_67_v05_n3_(3).pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2802&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_104_v05_n3_(4).pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2806&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_106_v05_n3_(5).pdf',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2=2809&nomeArquivo=Vol5No3_107_v05_n3_editorial.pdf']
```

I'm new to Python so I apologize in advance for any obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried it for the first two urls in your list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

add_url = ['http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=1',
 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed=10',]

pat = 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/'

add_doi = []
for i in add_url:
    html = requests.get(i).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    add_doi.extend([pat+i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile(r'audiencia_pdf.asp\?aid2'))])
```

and you get 103 results.

The main idea is to start with an empty list of results `add_doi`, and then extend it by adding new results coming from the scraped urls.

The core of the script is the final line that finds all hrefs containing the pattern `audiencia_pdf.asp\?aid2`.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you did differently? Why I was only getting a few?

Comment: @anaclc You can find a brief explanation of the code.

Comment: I get it now, I wasn't adding new results then! That's why that last line is so important!

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help you save the PDF.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding=utf-8
import io,os
from simplified_scrapy.core.utils import md5
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider,SimplifiedDoc
class PdfSpider(Spider):
  name = 'quimicanova.sbq.org.br'
  def __init__(self):
    if(not os.path.exists('pdf/')):
      os.mkdir('pdf/')
    host = 'http://www.quimicanova.sbq.org.br/default.asp?ed='
    self.start_urls = [host + str(i) for i in range(1,285)] # Initialize variable start_urls
    Spider.__init__(self,self.name) #necessary

  def afterResponse(self, response, url):
    try:
      # save pdf
      if(response.code==200 and url.find('audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2')>0):
        name = 'pdf/'+md5(url)+'.pdf'
        file = io.open(name, "ab")
        file.write(response.read())
        file.close()
        return None
      else:
        html = Spider.afterResponse(self, response, url)
        return html
    except Exception as err:
      print (err)

  def extract(self, url,html,models,modelNames):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    lstA = doc.listA(url=url['url'])
    urls = []
    for u in lstA:
      if u['url'].find('audiencia_pdf.asp?aid2')>0:
        urls.append(u)

    return {"Urls": urls, "Data": urls} # Return data to framework

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(PdfSpider()) # Start crawling
```